# Git doesn't work after upgrading Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: git, macos, osx-elcapitan, xcrun

Git doesn't work after upgrading Mac OS X El Capitan.

After installing El Capitan, I have this error when I'm doing a git command:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Thanks Nafsaka for the highlight.

Here is the solution: Reinstalling Xcode Command Line Tools via Terminal

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: To add to this, if you ever have the joys of installing the GH bundled git, and/or home-brew and you find git breaks too (or you find that your developer tools start randomly playing up) then revert them back. Check by ` which git | xargs spctl -v -a `  without the quotes.. If it comes back with "no usable signature: reguected", it's not Apple original

Comment: Thanks for posting this, it's the same when you update to Sierra